# Min value of $a\sec \theta +b\cos \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Min value of$$a\sec \theta +b\cos \theta$$ for $$\theta \in (-90^\circ,90^\circ) $$

I have trouble in approaching this problem .Could only a method/hint be given ? I would to try it myself.

Comment: Do you know $a \ge 0$? Or does $a<0$ need to be considered?

Comment: It is easier in radians with $\theta \in (-\frac \pi2,\frac \pi2)$ so you can find where the derivative is $0$

Comment: @Henry all values sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the minimum value of function
$$f(\theta)=a\sec (\theta) +b\cos (\theta) \qquad \text{with}\qquad -\frac \pi 2 \leq \theta \leq \frac \pi 2 $$ Its derivative is

$$f'(\theta)=a \tan (\theta ) \sec (\theta )-b \sin (\theta )=\sin(\theta )\big[a \sec ^2(\theta )-b \big]$$

So, beside the trivial $\theta$, for other roots we need $a\,b >0$ and in such a case $$\theta_*=\sec ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)$$ (remember that the function is even). So, now we have
$$f(0)=a+b \qquad \text{with} \qquad f''(0)=a-b$$
$$f(\theta_*)=2\sqrt{ab} \qquad \text{with} \qquad f''(\theta_*)=2(b-a) \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}} $$
So, by the second derivative test, if $a > b$ the minimum value is $(a+b)$ at $\theta=0$ and if $a < b$ the minimum value is $2\sqrt{ab}$ at $\theta=\theta_*$.

Answer (score 2):

Try finding the derivative of the expression, and equate it to $0$.
Like Henry pointed out, this would be easier to do in radians, as handling derivatives in degrees can get cluttered.

Comment: Sir I got 2√ab and a+b which would be smaller ?

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution as a function of $a$ and $b$ is very difficult to calculate, even with numerical values. Indeed, the derivative equal to zero gives the equation $$b\cos^3(x)=a\sin(x)$$
which leads to a polynomial equation of sixth degree in $\cos(x)$ quite difficult to solve.

The real solutions of this equation given by Wolfram calculator is showed in the attached figure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a,b>0$, then
$$a\sec \theta +b\cos \theta=(\sqrt{a\sec\theta } - \sqrt{b\cos\theta })^2 +2\sqrt{ab }\ge 2 \sqrt{ab }
$$
Others cases of $a,b$ can be examined similarly.